# Trigger em Mysql para ser disparada sempre que um campo for editado

Tags: mysql, sql-update, trigger

Boas colegas, estou com um problema que ainda não consegui resolver. Pretendo criar um trigger que sempre que a coluna de quantidade de produto sofrer um update ele dispare uma acção para uma outra tabela, para permitir ao usuário saber que um determinado produto sofreu uma acréscimo ou diminuição. É possível no mysql? Se sim como, qual seria a lógica?

Tabela que sofrera update no campo quantidade

```
'producto', 'CREATE TABLE `producto` (\n  
idProducto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n 
 `artigo` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `data` datetime NOT NULL,\n 
 `tipoProducto` varchar(50) NOT NULL,\n 
 `descricao` mediumtext NOT NULL,\n  
`quantidade` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  
`validade` date DEFAULT NULL,\n 
 PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Tabela em que será disparada a acão

```
`'entrada_producto', 'CREATE TABLE `entrada_producto` (\n  
`idEntrada` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n 
 `idProducto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n 
 `dataEntrada` datetime DEFAULT NULL,\n 
 `quantidade_entrada` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n 
 `descricao` mediumtext,\n
 PRIMARY KEY (`idEntrada`),\n  KEY `idProducto` (`idProducto`),\n  CONSTRAINT `entrada_producto_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idProducto`) REFERENCES `producto` (`idproducto`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'`
```

Answer (score -1):

Podes fazer uma trigger conforme abaixo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER produto_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON producto FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

if (NEW.quantidade <> OLD.quantidade)
THEN

/*  insert modulos (descricao) values ('Teste');  Aqui você faz o que quiser, coloquei uma tabela qualquer só para mostrar */


END IF;
END $$;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Essa sintaxe não é para o sql server? Tentei correr mas não tive resposta nem do workbench nem do command line client…

Comment: @AyrtonPereira não, esta é do Mysql Mesmo.
 Eu rodei aqui e funcionou, veja se não faltou algum detalhe, (o delimiter talvez ou o END $$